# .net core Convert byte[] to list<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core

in my project I use `ISession` to store a string list in session cache like this:

```
var cacheData= someStringList;
var byteArrayCache = CacheHelper.convertListToByteArray(cacheData);
HttpContext.Session.Set(CacheKeys.CacheKey, byteArrayCache);
```

the `ISession` `Set` method needs a `byte[]` as `parameter`.

Then I execute the `GET` method like this:

```
var byteArrayResponse = HttpContext.Session.Get(CacheKeys.CacheKey);
```

This `GET` is returned as a `byte[]` and I need to convert back to string list but I'm not being able to achieve it.

Any Ideas?

the `ConvertListToByteArray` method is the following:

```
 public static byte[] convertListToByteArray(List<string> list)
        {
            byte[] dataAsBytes = list.SelectMany(s =>
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s + Environment.NewLine)).ToArray();

            return dataAsBytes;
        }
```

Comment: Do the opposite of what you do in `CacheHelper.convertListToByteArray`?

Comment: is not that simple, i'll add that code on the question

Comment: It is that simple, though. `convertByteArrayToList(byte[] b) => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b).Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList()`.

Comment: You need to start by choosing a more reliably reversible way of converting the list to a byte array. If a string has a newline in it, it would become two separate strings coming back out. There's no way to distinguish between the element separator and actual data.

Comment: the string is always on the same format

Comment: @JeroenMostert that really worked, you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

To convert the byte[] into List: You will need to remove the newline from the byte[] then loop through each char then add to the new list.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(byte byt in dataAsBytes) {
if(!byt.Equals(Environment.NewLine)) {
list.Add(byt.ToString());
}
}
return list.ToList();
```